# Is there any way to report down-voter?

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

I wonder if there any system where we can report against those down-voters **who does not care enough to explain the reason**.

Sometimes its really bugs us out when someone down-vote the question or answer without any explanation. Even we don't know who is actually down-voted (as far as i know, may be I am wrong) the answer or question.

Comment: @SpritsDracula Indeed. Also, don't worry about serial downvotes. They get reversed automatically (if detected by the system at 00:00 UTC)

Comment: It's been discussed before on Meta. I think the main argument against was that it would theoretically open people to retribution. But the real reason is probably laziness.

Comment: StackOverflow works on the concept of up and down votes to rate the content of questions and answers. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) explains how things work, and no where in the description of voting does it require that the downvoter identify him/herself or explain why. (Most people do, however, as a courtesy to the poster of  the question.) The FAQ also mentions that discussions of *how* SO works should be posted to the meta site. And a search of the meta site would probably show you that this question has been asked already, and would end up being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Downvoting serves as a way of user moderation - if a question is bad it should be downvoted so other people don't waste their time on it. As to not stating reasons for downvotes, why should I bother writinig a comment on a question where the asker obviously didn't bother to spend three minutes with google, or read the faq, or inform himself about the type of questions one should and should not ask here.

Comment: Downvotes on meta has a different conotation from those on the main site: they are as likely to mean that people disagree with you as to mean they think the question was ill-posted or inappropriate. In this case, you are likely to get hammered because we've been over this ground *dozens* of times.

Comment: I am extremely sorry broz, actually i am new in stackoverflow and i did not know about meta.stackoverflow.com. If i knew that, i would have search for it and yes! 100% i will get the answer. I posted this question in stackoverflow and now it has been moved in meta section by moderator. So, I am getting hammered, but its ok, sometimes people get pretty much excited when they saw something wrong and instead of correcting it, they hammered for it as much as they can. But don't worry, still we got some good minded people who learn us how to overcome the problem. Anyway, thanks to all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't a procedure to report down-votes and there shouldn't be one. Down-votes are by design anonymous and while we do [encourage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) users to explain their down-votes, it is not compulsory.